# accessing woocommerce api in wordpress with sub directory installtion

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woothemes

I have wordpress installed in a sub-directory and not on the web-root. I have enabled woocoommerce REST api, but i am not able to access it. What will be my woocommerce rest api end points.

```
When i access using http://www.domainname.com/blog/wc-api/v1/orders
```

it returns 1.

```
When i access using http://www.domainname.com/home/wc-api/v1/orders
```

it returns 1.

When i access using http://www.domainname.com/wc-api/v1/orders

it gives me a message saying

```
woocommerce_api_authentication_error: Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match
```

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thanks.